# A pygame character isn't moving upon a key being pressed

Tags: python, pygame, game-development, pygame-surface

I am making a game in pygame, although when I want to move my player, pygame isn't moving the character. It is registering that a key has been pressed but nothing happens. Can someone please tell where the error is coming from and point me to the right direction. The following is my code.

Please not that the game is not fully developed.

```
import pygame as pg, random as r, sys

pg.init()
window = pg.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
pg.display.set_caption("The Pygame Version")

White = (255, 255, 255)
Black = (0, 0, 0)
Green = (0, 255, 0)
Red = (255, 0, 0)
DarkGreen = (0, 126, 0)
def draw():
    global runner, chaser
    background = pg.draw.rect(window, Green, (0, 0, 1200, 600))
    chaser = pg.draw.rect(window, Black, (1015, 225, 150, 150))
    runner = pg.draw.rect(window, Red, (30, 225, 150, 150))
   
    track1 = pg.draw.line(window, DarkGreen, (0, 200), (1200, 200),10)
    track2 = pg.draw.line(window, DarkGreen, (0, 400), (1200, 400),10)

score = 0
font = pg.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 28)
scoreBoard = font.render("Score: 0", True, Black)

speed = 150
text = 0
collision = 0
draw()
while True:
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if keys[pg.K_w]:
        runner.y -= 200
        runner.width = 300
        draw()
        print ("We are moving")
pg.quit()
```

Comment: `draw()` doesn't read `runner.y` or `runner.width`. If that's all you change when a key is pressed, why do you expect `draw()` to do anything different? Also you're not calling [`pygame.display.update`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) either which is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing rectangles at constant positions and with constant size:

> ```py
> chaser = pg.draw.rect(window, Black, (1015, 225, 150, 150))
> runner = pg.draw.rect(window, Red, (30, 225, 150, 150))
> ```

Note, `pygame.draw.rect` returns a new rectangle bounding the changed pixels. It actually returns `pygame.Rect(1015, 225, 150, 150)` respectively `pygame.Rect(30, 225, 150, 150)`

---

You have to do it the other way around:

Create `pygame.Rect` objects `chaser` and `runner`

```py
chaser = pg.Rect(1015, 225, 150, 150)
runner = pg.Rect(30, 225, 150, 150)
```

And use the objects to draw rectangles in `draw`:

```py
def draw():
    global runner, chaser
    pg.draw.rect(window, Green, (0, 0, 1200, 600))
    
    pg.draw.rect(window, Black, chaser)
    pg.draw.rect(window, Red, runner)

    # [...]
```